# asp:Panel runat="server" not available in C# .cs code page

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, sitecore

**My ascx page:**

```
<%@ Control Language="c#"  Inherits="FSB.Layouts.Short_Home_Loan_Application" CodeBehind="Short Home Loan Application.ascx.cs" %>    
<div class="form">
<form action="" method="post" rel="shortForm">
    <div class="section">        
         <asp:panel id="shortForm_wrapper" runat="server">
            this is the first panel
         </asp:panel>
         <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="thankYouWrapper" >this is the second panel</asp:Panel>
    </div>     
</form>
</div>

<sc:sublayout runat="server" path="~/layouts/FSB/Document Checklist Lightbox.ascx" id="checklist" />
```

**My CS Page:**

```
using System;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;
using Sitecore.Links;
using Sitecore.Data.Fields;
using Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net;
using FSB.Helpers;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.SessionState;

namespace FSB.Layouts {

    public partial class Short_Home_Loan_Application : System.Web.UI.UserControl {    

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            thankYouWrapper // not accessible here
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** This is a CMS project and uses Sitecore. I don't actually know what it is may be this helps. I am totally new to C# and have been thrown into bunch of C# websites.

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: CodeBehind="Short Home Loan Application.ascx.cs" does the code behind page name actually have spaces in it? Could you remove them?

Comment: or can you use other control is code behind ??

Comment: @benni_mac_b actually the page name contains spaces

Comment: No I am not able to use any runat server control in the code page

Comment: your form doesn't have *runat="server"*

Comment: @RVG that dont solve my problem

Comment: Do you get any errors when you compile the control?

Comment: Error 149 The name 'thankYouWrapper' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @Champ: Is it a Compile Error or Runtime error?

Comment: @dotNETbeginner its a Compile Error

Comment: If you have 2 nested forms with runat=server it won't work, not sure if you can have client form posting inside a server form.  You have a  control asp:panel not asp:Panel?

Comment: did you try the answer that i had posted? It worked for me i tried that.

Comment: @Ankit: yes. actually i think it has some thing to do with CMS sitecore do you know that CMS. i have just seen it in this project. for now i have done the work around with the ajax request but don't know what actually problem is.

Comment: I found something similar try this
1.open your .ascx page in design view
2.right click anywhere on the page and select Refresh

(.ascx.designer.cs file may need to to be closed while doing refresh for this to work)

Answer (score 3):

I assume you have a Web Application Project instead of a WebSite Project. As such, in the Solution Explorer, navigate to your `*.ascx` file, expand it to see the C# code-behind and you will also see a `*.ascx.designer.cs` file. Delete that "designer" file. Next, right-click on your `*.ascx` file and select **Convert to Web Application** which will re-generate the designer file. Now try to access the control via C#.

Answer (score 0):

In your ascx page header, modify your  Inherits directive to include the Namespace prefix in your code behind.

**Revision**

I have taken your original markup **as posted** and placed it in a test web application, and it compiles cleanly with the proper references available in the codebehind using VS2010.

Is there any possibility that this control was originally authored under a different name, in a different namespace, or copied from a different project and pasted into a shell source file in this project? The problem you are experiencing seems directly tied to the absence of the intermediate files ASP.NET generates in the background to establish protected declarations for markup-based entities that can be referenced in the codebehind of the control's source. If, for some reason, VS2010 cannot detect the need for these intermediate files to be regenerated, the markup and source will become out of sync and fail in a manner similar to what you are experiencing. I obviously cannot guarantee that is the cause of your particular problem, but I would at least consider it a strong suspect.

I would respectfully suggest that you create an *entirely new control* within VS2010, via the "Add New Item->" option in Solution Explorer, and add *just the markup* from this control into the ascx file (not the directive line), and then see if the code-behind for that new control can reference the server-side elements.

Good luck.

Comment: Inherits="FSB.Layouts.Short_Home_Loan_Application"   hear FSB.Layouts. is the Namespace

Comment: Suspect the designer file has become corrupt. I would delete the existing source and just start over for this control.

Comment: I have added a note in my question may be it helps

Comment: Read the note, but I'm thinking for now it isn't part of the immediate problem. Did you try creating a new/clean control yet?

Comment: Think we're not quite on the same idea here - I'm not talking about adding a control to your *existing* markup, I'm talking about going to your web project/site in Solution Explorer, right-clicking, selecting "Add New Item->" and from the dialog, selecting "Web User Control", and creating a *completely new control* into which you could paste *just the markup* of the control which is giving you problems. I'm thinking this could point out that ASP.NET intermediate files are the source of your problem.

Comment: @Champ Did you ever attempt to create a new control in the project?

Answer (score 0):

use "CodeFile" instead of "CodeBehind"

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="FSB.Layouts.Short_Home_Loan_Application" CodeFile="Short Home Loan Application.ascx.cs" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust theses elements :

1 CodeFile

```
CodeFile="Short_Home_Loan_Application.ascx.cs" %> //AddCodeFile, and set the same name
```

2 Runat

Add `runat="server"` to your forms

3 And replace your Panel with `Div` Container