# display Html string 

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I am new to C#  and i want to display a html string (saved in database from ckEditor ) to the page as html

```
<div class="descriptionText">
 <% 
     Response.Write(dynamicHtml);
 %>
</div>
```

it display as:

```
<p> test &nbsp;ht<u>ml test </u>html<strong> test html&nbsp;</strong></p>
```

But is should be :

test  html test html **test html**

**NOTE :** please suggest solution in which I can do  Response.Write the string

Comment: It renders properly for me. Can you provide more information? What version of asp.net are you using? Are you sure the value of dynamic Html isn't html encoded by a prior process?

Comment: Your output is html encoded. Response.Write should not do that on its own. You mentioned you use sitecore. I figure that might be responsible for the encoding somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
<div class="descriptionText">
 <asp:Literal runat="server" id="lit"/>
</div>
```

in your codebehind, bind your HTML to the literal:

```
lit.Text = dynamicHtml;
```

i'm assuming you are getting the HTML text from a database through some query, you basically have to bind the result to the literal.

UPDATE:
this seems to be working aswell for me:

In your ASPX page:

```
 <%= dynamicHtml %>
```

in your code behind:

```
protected string dynamicHtml { get; set; }
```

page load:

```
 dynamicHtml = "your HTML";
```

Comment: sorry forget to mention: please don't include any tool server side tool. i need it use responce.write  .... :(

Comment: why's that? any particular reason ?

Comment: yes. i am using site-core and already facing a problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12404924/asppanel-runat-server-not-available-in-c-sharp-cs-code-page   still no solution for this  I am not able to include any server side control

Comment: ok, but i'm wondering how you get the value for dynamicHtml then ?

Comment: executed the query on database and declared the dynamichtml as  protected variable to and is accessable to axpx page

Comment: i updated my answer with another possibility that doesn't require any runat="server" things. Just fyi :)

Answer (score 3):

You may need this scriplet, Read more about Response.Write [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525585%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

```
<%=  Response.Write(dynamicHtml); %>
```

If it is possible for you to have code behind then make div server accessible by add `runat="server"` and assign it some `id`

**Html**

```
<div id="divMessage" class="descriptionText" runat="server">

</div>
```

**Code Behind**

```
divMessage.InnerHTML = dynamicHtml
```